# FileUpload with its updation status

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to make a functionality where a User will upload the file and its name and description will be shown in the gridview.

Now here what I want is, if the same file has some changes, it needs to be uploaded again and the since its uploaded for the second time. I will be having one more column as `FileRevision` which will show the no of times files has been updated.

See the image for your reference:-

[image: Image for ref]

Do let me know from where to start.

Comment: @SamAxe: Updation is, how many times the file has been updated with the changes

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @Amit: I need to make this functionality and need the guidance from where to start these

Comment: Everytime user uploads the file, increment the FileRevision by 1. Then display the column value. What's the problem?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes, that is what I want. I have never done that before, can you help me related that. How to increment it by 1

Comment: How do you distinguish one file from another? Based on their file name?

Comment: @khlr: Yes, based on the filename

Comment: That may be a problem. What do you do, if you upload *document1.doc* and I have a *sheet1.xls* but rename it to *document1.doc*. Will your service put my file as revision 2 in place?

Comment: @khlr: I want to make that service. Can you help with that

Comment: You'll need to provide some more information: does the user have to be logged in to use your service? What have you done so far? Does you service already do anything? The screenshot shows you application or is just for demonstration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done by myself, like below:-

`FileUpload Control` in **ASPX page**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fupreportfile" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ValidationGroup="AddNew" />
```

Now, on button click it will check whether the file Exist or not. Checking thorugh CS code:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                if (fupreportfile.HasFiles)
                {
                    int count = CheckFileExists(fupreportfile.PostedFile.FileName);
                    fupreportfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ReportFolder/" + fupreportfile.PostedFile.FileName));

                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = " Update tbl_reports SET revision=@revision Where Id=@Id";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", GetIdByFileName(fupreportfile.PostedFile.FileName));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@revision", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (count + 1).ToString();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Reports updated sucessfully');window.location ='csrreports.aspx';", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_reports (NgoId,report_type_id,report_title,report_file,report_desc,revision) values(@NgoId, @report_type_id, @report_title,@report_file,@report_desc,@revision)", conn);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlNgoName.SelectedValue;
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@report_type_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlReportType.SelectedValue;
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@report_title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtreporttitle.Text;
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@report_file", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fupreportfile.PostedFile.FileName;
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@report_desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtreportdescription.Text;
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@revision", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (count + 1).ToString();
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Reports added sucessfully');window.location ='csrreports.aspx';", true);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Code for checking file :-

```
public int CheckFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_reports WHERE report_file=@report_file", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@report_file", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;
            con.Open();
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Also, I need to check the ID for which Row it is updating. So the code for that is

```
public int GetIdByFileName(string fileName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM tbl_reports WHERE report_file=@report_file", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@report_file", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;
            con.Open();
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return count;
        }
    }
```

I checked this and it worked for me :)